# Do the right-chiral electron and left-chiral positron interact with the anti-$W$ boson?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, antimatter, weak-interaction, chirality

I've been reading Flip Taneda's 'quantum diaries' articles, and he references the famous fact that the W boson (weak force) only interacts with left-handed electrons and right-handed positron.

BUT... Does the antimatter-W interact with the right-handed electron and left-handed positron?

Comment: Answer unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A $W^-$ can decay to an L electron and a R antineutrino.

Its antiparticle, the $W^+$ decays to a R positron and a L neutrino.

In our purely chiral weak-interaction charged-current world, these are the ***only*** options.

---

N.B. of course, being massive, as soon as they are produced in the interaction vertex, the fermions will start changing (oscillating) their chirality as they propagate, since the mass term in the lagrangian links (converts) L with R. This is an "academic" phenomenon, hardly practically significant, except perhaps in [Zitterbewegung](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjc/s10052-007-0222-x).

Comment: how about this  physics.stackexchange.com/questions/566209/elegant-theoretical-ways-to-prove-the-u1-electric-charge-of-electron-proto ?